# asp.net mvc jquery form upload

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, jquery-forms-plugin

I am using jQuery form up to upload the file but am unable to return any message from the controller. Am I doing it right below?

```
$(function() {
    $('#fileUploadForm').ajaxForm({               
        type: "POST",
        dataType: "json",             
        beforeSubmit: ShowRequest,
        success: SubmitSuccesful,
        error: AjaxError                               
    });                                    
});   

function ShowRequest(formData, jqForm, options) {
    var queryString = $.param(formData);
    return true;
}

function AjaxError() {
    $("#msgs").html("A file upload error occured.");
}

function SubmitSuccesful(responseText, statusText) {
    $("#fileUploadForm").unblock();
    $.growlUI(null, responseText.message);
}
```

```cs
public FileUploadJsonResult AjaxPostTypeUpload(HttpPostedFileBase postedFile)
{
    try
    {
        string mess = string.Empty;          
        mess = "success";              
        return new FileUploadJsonResult { Data = new { message = mess }};
    }
    catch { throw; }
}
```

Comment: If you put a breakpoint in your `AjaxPostTypeUpload` is it stopping there?

Comment: i didn't get you, what do you mean by stopping there?

Comment: By `stopping there` I mean, does the code stop at the breakpoint.

Comment: yes it is calling AjaxPostTypeUpload

Answer (score 2):

Try just returning a basic object with the `success` parameter:

```
return new { message = "success" };
```

Comment: ok works but not returning textarea in the response will not cause any problem? can you clarify?

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by 'not returning textarea in the response'? This is technically no different from what you were doing in your example, the only difference is the format of the JSON response.